# Diagonalizability of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

For a 3 X 3 upper triangular matrix,can we look at the matrix and tell whether its diagonalizable? What conditions need to be satisfied by the elements for it to be diagonalizable?

Comment: A sufficient condition would be that $a_{ii} \neq a_{jj}$ when $i \neq j$--that is, that diagonal terms are distinct. I assume you're looking for a condition that's both necessary and sufficient though.

Comment: No. Thats not what I want. What if there are two diagonal elements that are same? Then what conditions should be satisfied?

Answer (score 1):

The 3x3 matrix $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if it has three linearly independent eigenvectors.  When $A$ is triangular, its eigenvalues are in plain view right there on the diagonal.  Can you find a linearly independent set of eigenvectors that corresponds to these eigenvalues?

If all three eigenvalues of $A$ are the same and $A$ is not already diagonal, you will not be able to do this.  For in that case the eigenvalue equation is
$$
(rI + N) v = rv
$$
where $N$ is obtained from $A$ by setting each diagonal element $r$ to zero. Any $v$ that satisfies this equation must be in the nullspace of $N$, but this nullspace has dimension 3 if and only if $N$ is the zero matrix.

If all three eigenvalues of $A$ are different, then it's a standard result that $A$ *is* diagonalizable, as has been observed already in the comments.

This leaves the case in which two eigenvalues are the same and the third is different. Suppose first that $A$ has the form
$$
A = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} r & b & c \\ 0 & r & d \\ 0 & 0 & s\end{array}\right]
$$
Can we find two linearly independent solutions to $Av = rv$?  The answer is yes if and only if the nullity of the matrix
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & b & c \\ 0 & 0 & d \\ 0 & 0 & s-r\end{array}\right]
$$
is 2, which holds only if $b=0$ assuming that $r$ and $s$ are different.

Other cases in which two eigenvalues are the same can be handled similarly.

Comment: Yes. Thats the conclusion I came to but I didn't have a proof. Thanks for that. Now suppose its a general n x n matrix. Then what should the condition be? I think that the the place where the row and column with the same diagonal element intersect that should be zero. In the matrix you took, b is in that place.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure you're right.